# No link to change user's password in Plone4

Tags: plone

I'm quite new to plone, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find a way to change a password for users. Taking plain vanilla plone4 (4.3, but I think it is the same in 4.2), after user login, I can't find a link to change a password. If I go directly to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@change-password
```

Form to change password is there and it is working, but I can't find a link in web pages. Am I missing something obvious or an option in site setup or ZMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the third tab on the user's personal information page, the click path is: (user's name) -> preferences -> then select the third tab in the content area, they are:

- Personal Information
- Personal Preferences (preselected)
- Password

That tab is only visible if the member succeeds at canPasswordSet, which I'd guess is comprised of having the "Set Own Password" permission and some things in the property layer (e.g., if you authenticate with a read-only LDAP, you don't get a password link).

Comment: That is the thing, there is no third tab there, only the tab to edit your details and a tab to change couple preferences (pre-selected).

Comment: That tab is only visible if the member succeeds at `canPasswordSet`, which I'd guess is comprised of having the "Set Own Password" permission and some things in the property layer (e.g., if you authenticate with a read-only LDAP, you don't get a password link).

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. If I can go directly to @@change-password and it actually changes the password, that should mean, that I have a `canPasswordSet` permission. However, after playing with enable self registration, set own password, that tab appeared, and it looks like it is not possible to switch it off now, even if change everything back. Something is weird going on with plain plone... Anyway, thanks:)